# Trust a device for more then 30 days in Google Two-Factor Authentication

Tags: google-account, security, authentication, multi-factor-auth

When I log on to my Google account and have to enter a two-factor code, I get an option to trust this device for 30 days:

[image: screenshot]

Some time ago, this option trusted the device permanently - which is a lot more comfortable, at least for your main device. Is there still a way to permanently trust a device?

Answer (score 2):

Google set this as an default value and didn't provide any option to change this settings. BUt you can give this as a product feedback where they will change it based on the number of request